# Changed a picklist field to not have a default value, but it still populates new contacts with one

Tags: picklist, contact, default-value

I modified an existing Contact picklist field to no longer have a default value (it previously did). However, new Contacts still get set with a default value and I'm not sure why. Here's the field setup:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was a record type issue. Got it fixed!

**EDIT:** Here's how I did it for others with this problem:

1. Go to the object and find "Record Types" in the setup menu

[image]

2. For each record type of that object, click on the name of the record type (don't click "edit")

[image]

3. You'll see a list of picklist fields available for that record type. Find the one in question and click "edit"

[image]

4. Set the default value

[image]

5. Rinse and repeat for all other record types of that object

Comment: From review: Adding a more detailled answer would be great for others having the same issue in the future.